# Настройка htaccess. Поддомены

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Нужно перенаправлять запрос с определенных поддоменов в определенные папки. Есть такие наработки:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

НО:

1. При переходе по домену `sub.example.ru` не открывает статику.
2. Никак не могу запретить переход по ссылке `example.ru/sub/`

Как грамотно распределять запросы по папкам с определенных поддоменов, а остальные направлять в index.html?

Comment: Почемубы не использовать для этого виртуальные хосты?

Comment: @Nick нет возможности, все это делается на хостинге

Comment: Если у вас хостинг попросите техподдержке ребят они вам сделают. На beget я один раз обращался мне сделали.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет запрета перехода по ссылке example.ru/sub/, могу предложить такое:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^sub1\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/sub1\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^sub2\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/sub2\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^sub3\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/sub3\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Cтатика должна тоже открываться, т.к. весь контент будет в example.com/sub. К сожалению проверить не было возможности

Остальное можно преводить в index.html с помощью

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/index.html" [R=301,L]
```

PS, для последнего редиректа необходимо будет создание *.example.com хоста в httpd.conf с DocumentRoot таким же как у example.com